# Yii2 remote logout a user session from the user current session

Tags: php, session, redis, yii2, logout

I wanted to logout a user session logged in a different browser/environment from the current session of the same user. A feature similar to this - https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&view.

**Yii2** is the backend framework used. Using **redis** for session management - **yii2-redis**. I also save the session ids saved in database.

I followed this article - 
http://www.codeinphp.com/general/php-code-snippets/remotely-destroy-different-session-php-forced-user-signout/

But didn't had any success.

```
session_id($old_session_id);
session_start(); // This line throws error.
session_destroy();
```

Deleting the key in redis using `\Yii::$app->session->destroySession($oldSessionId)` didn't logout.

Changing the session id to old one and then destroying the session also didn't work.

```
$currentSessionId = \Yii::$app->session->getId();
\Yii::$app->session->setId($oldSessionId);
\Yii::$app->getSession()->destroy();
\Yii::$app->session->setId($currentSessionId);
```

If anyone had success in implementing this successfully, please share your solution. Also if there is any documentation regarding this which can help, please do provide.

Comment: Thanks to @Ngô Văn Thao and @Nate for their answers. This is the approach I followed taking inputs from their answers.

Set `enableAutoLogin` to false.
Create a `session` table(user_id, session_id) along with other attributes related to device, browser.
In the `afterLogin ` method, add user_id and session_id to the `session` table. To logout a session remotely, destroy session using -Yii::$app->session->destroySession(sessionId) and change the auth_key of the user.

Note: This didn't work for the default Session component. Works fine with `yii\redis\Session`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first, `session_start()` must be call before `session_id()` and just call only once

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
   session_start();
}
session_id($old_session_id);
session_destroy();
```

But just remove session, that is not enough if you allow user auto login because browser will auto login by using cookies. To solve, you must change user `AuthKey` - Yii2 use `AuthKey` to validate user auto login. By default each user have only one `AuthKey` in user table so that when you change `AuthKey` user logout anywhere. So we have to custom. Create for each user session an `AuthKey`, stored somewhere not in user table. Do it easy: extends yii\web\User class override `afterLogin` function to create `AuthKey` for each login session. override `validateAuthKey` function to validate auto login use our custom `AuthKey`. Now when you want to kill any user session : kill PHP session id and `AuthKey` that session will be logout right away.
I have been using this solution for my projects and it works fine.

Comment: Not working for me. I have autoLogin set to true. I use username + password based login similar to https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/LoginForm.php. Changing the auth_key just updates the _identity cookie and doesn't logout the session. Can you please share some sample code of your implementation. Also what kind of login you use.

Comment: you must kill both AuthKey and PHP session same as how you did

Comment: change or remove `AuthKey` just prevent auto login, kill php session will kill user session right away.

Comment: I did both remove auth_key and also destroy the session. But the remote user session didn't logout.

Comment: Try to disable auto login. do your user logout after you remove session ?

Comment: Ngo solution works. Confirmed. You do have to change the authkey AND delete the session entry both for it to work. But it works at least.

Comment: By disabling autoLogin, the session is no more valid on closing the browser. I want to persist the session even after browser is closed and re-opened. Also, the session timeout value for the rememberMe is no more valid.  Is there a way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: I tried enabling autoLogin and was still able to do remote logout. However, the new issue is when i close the browser and reopen, the autologin logins the user. But it creates a new session id and therefore a new row in session table. This creates confusion for the user since it keeps creating new sessions without login. Is there a way to identify the old session logged in from the closed browser and delete it?

Comment: waiting for my tutorial

Comment: In the afterLogin method, cookieBased flag gives an indication mentioning that cookie based login happened. So, instead of saving a new row in session table, the old session id needs to be updated with new one. However, old session id was not retrievable either in beforeLogin or afterLogin methods. Any idea on how to retrieve the old session id. One possible solution can be save a copy of the PHPSESSID in another cookie and read it in afterLogin and update it with new sessionid. Are there any better ways of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ngo's answer, I figured out a method that works well and is easier to setup.

1) Add a "last_session_id" field to your user table.

2) Add following to your main controller:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);

    if(Yii::$app->user->id)
    {
        //update the user table with last_session_id
        $user = User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        $user->last_session_id = Yii::$app->session->id;
        $user->save(false);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

3) Change site/login action to following:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {

        //delete previous session ID and change auth key
        Yii::$app->session->destroySession(Yii::$app->user->identity->last_session_id);
        $u = \common\models\User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        $u->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        $u->save(false);
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('/site/login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```